# Get values from an Array and SimpleXmlElement Obcject

Tags: php, arrays, xml, curl

Given a deep array, how do you display line-delimited values from it?

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
      [godzina] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
          [0] => 17:00:00 
      ) 
      [data] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
          [0] => 2015-09-02 
     ) 
    [kurs] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
         [0] => 2.03 
    ) 
  ) 

)
```

This is the output I'm expecting:

```
hours: 17:00:00
date: 2015-09-02
exchange: 2.03
```

I get this array from an xml, via curl, so the source can't be altered.

Comment: my array names $zmt
code: echo $zmt[0]['godzina']->[0];

gives an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is in a variable `$myArr`, you should be able to do a simple [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($myArr[0] as $k => $v) {
  echo $k.": ".$v[0]."\n"
}
```

Comment: Ok, got it! but how to separate it?

I mean I, need first echo the hour, then echo a date (in other html tag), etc. This values must be in separated variable I guess...

Comment: Do I need get $v[0] by key?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'separate it'? And no, you shouldn't need to, but if you're not sure what `$v` is, try `echo var_export($v, true)."\n"`

Answer (score 2):

Figured Out:

```
$h = 'godzina';
$hvalue = $zmt[$h];
$d = 'data';
$dvalue = $zmt[$d];
$e = 'kurs';
$evalue = $zmt[$e];
```

and then echo with [0].

BUT thanks. For foreach loop.